# How to filter a leaflet plot using dateRangeInput?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I am trying to filter markers on a `leaflet` plot using a `dateRangeInput` filter. When I launch the app and change the date nothing happens to the markers and the only change is the map seems to zoom in a bit?

Any advice would be extremely helpful!

See code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

incident_date <-  as.Date(c("2018-10-05", "2019-02-01", "2013-11-04", "2021-08-01", "2022-07-03", 
                        "2013-12-22", "2019-05-15", "2020-11-08", "2023-05-02", "2022-12-29", 
                        "2021-04-10", "2021-01-23", "2019-02-07", "2021-12-11", "2019-10-06"))

gps_latitude <- c(-30.84338, -30.89331, -30.89220, -33.16041, -30.85012, 
                  -30.94844, -28.19297, -27.36132, -31.67199, -25.33637,
                  -34.21453, -29.18217, -27.10775, -27.29060, -30.15939)

gps_longitude <- c(148.2846, 148.2842, 148.2776, 147.1258, 148.1226, 
                   148.2580, 149.9828, 150.1055, 147.8641, 150.5783, 
                   147.0175, 149.5341, 150.2014, 150.1405, 148.6335)

df <- data.frame(incident_date, gps_latitude, gps_longitude)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css",
             "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map",
                width = "100%",
                height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(bottom = 10, right = 10,
                dateRangeInput("map_date_range",
                               "Select Date Range:",
                               start = min(df$incident_date),
                               end = max(df$incident_date),
                               min = min(df$incident_date),
                               max = max(df$incident_date),
                               format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                               separator = " to "))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_reactive <- reactive({
    df %>% 
      filter(incident_date >= input$map_date_range[1],
             incident_date <= input$map_date_range[2])
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data_reactive()) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(lat = ~gps_latitude, lng = ~gps_longitude,
                 clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>% 
      addCircles(lat = ~gps_latitude, lng = ~gps_longitude)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post a sample `df` data frame so that someone can help you.

Comment: Impossible to answer without a reproducible example of your data, but I suspect you need some `as.Date` somewhere

Comment: Sorry! I should have added that earlier. I have updated the post with a example dataframe. Thank you :)

Comment: Which dates are you providing? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ah, actually, this code does work! This was a simple version of the original script. In the original script I did not have as.Date classed correctly (in this example I did).  Sorry for the confusion, but thank you for your time! This did help me figure out the issue.